# What built-in MongoDB roles permit a user to create a new databases and users for all databases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-roles

MongoDB's documentation is clear about roles needed for other operations. I may be overlooking something, but I couldn't find a clear description of how to create a new database.

I am trying to do this from a remote Node.js server. One that should be able to create databases and create users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) you need the [`dbAdmin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin) and [`userAdmin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdmin) roles, but the [`dbOwner`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner) role also can fit your needs (depends on the details of your task). Also you can [create a custom role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/).